# RowDataBound, buttonfield and boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, rowdatabound

I want to use RowDataBound in order to make sure that the download button(buttonfield) in each row will download the right file according to file name(bondfield) but I have no idea how to make it, since I still new in asp.net and C#. Can anyone give me some idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just bind Command Argument property of your button in grid with bond field.
then on RowDataBound Event just find button and assign downloaded link to it.

or if you want to perform something  button click then find your button in RowCommand Event of grid. Assign command name to button.

Visit this link it will help you.
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36528/GridView-all-in-one)